# How can I get location data (country,city, etc.) by giving latitude and longtitude using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Currently I'm using the following query :

```sql
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y),4326);
```

and it returns me location in numbers something like :

`010100000000000000008012300000000000001230`

but I wanted to get location data as text instead.

Comment: Do you want the well-known text representation of the geometry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry), or do you want some more human-oriented information (city name, country, etc.)?

Comment: Try: ST_AsText https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html...

Comment: for example i want to give lat and long and in return to get let's say "county:Russia, city:Moscow"
is that possible with postgis?

Comment: What you're looking for is called `reverse geocoding`. It will of course required an internet connexion since the information should be stored somewhere on a server. There is already an extension available for postgreSQL called [Tiger Geocoder](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder)

Answer (score 5):

Under PostGIS, use the `ST_AsText` method ([documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html)) as :

```sql
SELECT
  ST_AsText(
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y),4326)
  );
```

or

```sql
SELECT
  ST_AsText(
    '010100000000000000008012300000000000001230'
  );
```

This should normally return (with your return example) :

`POINT(3.99422795673118e-77 3.8862758497925e-77)`

Comment: i tried both, its not exact what i want
for example i want to give lat and long and in return get let's say "county:Russia, city:Moscow"
is that possible with postgis?

Comment: It's possible if you have for example a country table and a city table in PostGIS (for exemple from OpenStreetMap) and make geography / geometry joins in the query.

Comment: I imported table with country table to my databases also i have postgis extension now i want to write query that will fetch moscow by lat and long
which SQL query should i use? can u write example pls

Comment: A countries table will give you `Russia`, not `Moscow`. With geography columns, use in `WHERE` clause `ST_COVERS(table_country.geom_column, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y),4326)` ([documentation here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html))